# Ajax request in PhantomJs script

Tags: jquery, ajax, phantomjs, local

**Problem:** Ajax request within phantomJs script to a local page doesn't work (no response)

**Question:** How can I make it work? Any ideas or possible solutions?

**Description:** I'm running a phantomJs script and I need to access some data that is provided by a php function in another page (local). In order to do that, I use an ajax request to that page inside the phantomjs script. However, the request doesn't do anything. The script is:

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function () {
        console.log("Solve Captcha");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'captcha.php',
            data: { filename: 'C:\\wamp\\www\\images\\0.png' },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (output) {
                console.log('Solved');
                phantom.exit();
            },
        });
    });
});
```

The php page is in a local WAMP server and it has been tested with ajax (outside a phantomJs script), and it works fine. The script and the php files are in the folder `C:\wamp\www`, while the image `0.png` is in the sub-folder `C:\wamp\www\images`.

**Important:** The page `captcha.php` is in the localhost, while phantomJs is requesting a page that is **not** local, that is, `page.open` opens a `url` that is not local.

I don't understand why making this request in a phantomJs script won't work. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`page.includeJs()` injects jQuery into the page, so it is only accessible from the page context (inside of `page.evaluate()`). The page context is sandboxed, so you cannot call `phantom.exit()` from the page context, because there is no such object `window.phantom`.

You have two possibilities to make it work.

#### Blocking AJAX

`jQuery.ajax()` accepts an `async: false` property to make a blocking AJAX call, so you can simply make the call and then continue with the execution in iterative style.

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function () {
        console.log("Solve Captcha");
        page.evaluate(function(){
            $.ajax({
                async: false, // this
                url: 'http://localhost/captcha.php',
                data: { filename: 'C:\\wamp\\www\\images\\0.png' },
                type: 'post',
                success: function (output) {
                    console.log('Solved');
                },
            });
        });
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

#### Wait for completion

[`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) from the examples can be used to wait for a specific condition to be set. This condition should be set in the `success` callback of the AJAX call:

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', function () {
        console.log("Solve Captcha");
        page.evaluate(function(){
            window._finishedCall = false;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/captcha.php',
                data: { filename: 'C:\\wamp\\www\\images\\0.png' },
                type: 'post',
                success: function (output) {
                    console.log('Solved');
                    window._finishedCall = true;
                },
            });
        });
        waitFor(function check(){
            return page.evaluate(function(){
                return window._finishedCall;
            });
        }, function onReady(){
            phantom.exit();
        }, 10000); // 10 seconds maximum timeout
    });
});
```

---

The second problem is that you want to make a cross-domain request, because `captcha.php` is on localhost and `url` is distinct from localhost. You need to run PhantomJS with the `--web-security=false` option and use fully qualified URLs: `http://localhost/captcha.php`.

Comment: Nothing is happening with the first solution (`async: false`). I think `page.evaluate` can't actually access `captcha.php` or `0.png`.

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: No errors, 'Solve Captcha' is printed on the console and it stays there. If I include `phantom.exit()` like in the solution, then the code exists immediately after 'Solve Captcha' is printed. I logged the output of the function and I'm getting a `null`.

Comment: Maybe you should register the ajax `error` callback to see whether there was a problem with the request.

Comment: So I removed the `async` property and added an error function and printed out the messages. I received `Unable to load resource (#16URL: **url of the page**_/captcha.php_)Error code: 203. Description: Error downloading **url of the page**_/captcha.php_ - server replied: Not Found`.        The **url of the page** is the url that I open with `page.open` and the `$.ajax` is trying to load `captcha.php` in THAT url, not in the LOCAL server.

Comment: Because of `page.evaluate` we're evaluating the `$.ajax` in the context of the page, so the `url: 'captcha.php'` ends up being evaluated in the context of the page `"url of the page"/captcha.php`. That's not what I want, `captcha.php` is in the local server (in my pc). Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: It was not entirely clear were everything is supposed to point to. I extended my answer accordingly. You should probably make that also clear in your question.

Comment: It now works! Thanks so much for taking the time to help me Artjom! I really appreciate it!