# Cannot put phantom.exit() inside page.evaluate() in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, callback, phantomjs

I have 2 code samples as following:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.youtube.com', function(s) {
  console.log(s);
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    var t = page.evaluate(function() {
      console.log('here');
       phantom.exit();     // case 1: inside page.evaluate()
    });

  });
});
```

-> In this case, phantom.exit() is put inside page.evaluate(), and error appears: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: phantom"

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.youtube.com', function(s) {
  console.log(s);
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    var t = page.evaluate(function() {
      console.log('here');
    });
    phantom.exit();            // case 2: outside page.evaluate()
  });
});
```

-> In case 2: phantom.exit() is put outside page.evaluate(). There is no error, but 'here' is not printed out.

=> Neither of 2 above ways can print out 'here'. Is there any effective way to print 'here' without error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use any of the `phantom` method inside of the page, in the same way the page itself can't use them.

The `phantom` object is a special host object provided by the runtime to the script it initially launches. Once a page has been loaded, the page runs in its own context with the usual browser variables, which do not include `phantom`.

You need to wait for the `page.evaluate` to call back to the phantom script, then call `exit` from there. The Phantom [docs show this exact case](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html), with `exit` being called after `evaluate` has returned. They don't seem to cover whether `evaluate` is blocking or not, but the example suggests that it may be.

To capture the log messages from the page, you need to subscribe to its [`onConsoleMessage` event](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html). The Phantom console only picks up messages from the script it is running, not any pages that it may load. All you need to do is route page messages to the phantom console:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log('PAGE: ' + msg);
};
```

Comment: thank you, I got your point :)

Can I ask you another question? If I put an ajax request inside page.evaluate(), $.post(url, function(data){//some code}), how can I get data and print it outside of page.evaluate() ?

Comment: @MrCold That's an interesting question. You could force the ajax call to be sync, which is poor practice but won't be harmful in a scripted browser. You could also use message passing between the host script and page, with a prefix/protocol, to send info back and forth. Then your workflow becomes a normal MPI async one.

Comment: @MrCold I got you covered with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28684532/1816580)

Comment: @ArtjomB. it seems like there is no "perfect" asynchronous solution for this case. I don't really want to use blocking AJAX since I have to deal with a huge amount of requests. If I used waitfor, I would have to set the time out as big as possible to ensure that every request will be handled, but it leads to the problem of using too much loop of setInterval().   Can you suggest me a better idea?

Comment: @MrCold Yes, you can use the `window.callPhantom`/`page.onCallback` pair as seen in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28925479/1816580).

Answer (score -1):

Try returning required data back and do console.log() after evaluation

Example

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://www.youtube.com', function(s) {
console.log(s);
page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
var t = page.evaluate(function() {
  return "here";
});
console.log(t);
phantom.exit();            // case 2: outside page.evaluate()
  });
});
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks I was wrong there, removed that line :)